# Optional keyword arguments - argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to make a program where there are 3 different options for keyword arguments input(the user must choose one of them):

1) The first one is when the user enters two integers so the program will be called like this :

```
python myProgram.py -s 3 -p 9
```

2) The second one is when the user enters a string of ones and zeros :

```
python myProgram.py -r 1101011010
```

3) The third input is the same as the second one, but it is stored in a different variable

```
python myProgram.py -l 1101011010
```

How can I implement this? I have read about argparse and nargs = '?' but I got confused and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: *keyboard* arguments? Do you perhaps mean *keyword* instead? In command-line terms, those are *optional* arguments.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sorry!

Comment: I recommend using subparsers instead, so that the usages of your program will be (1) `python myProgram.py command1 3 9` (2) `python myProgram.py command2 1101011010` (3) `python myProgram.py command3 1101011010` (give the commands proper names). This is much more friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mutual exclusion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) to create your 3 options (and mark the group as required). You'll have to manually test if `-s` is used if `-p` is present, however:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-s', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-p', type=int)

def binary(value):
    # just test if the value is a valid binary string
    try:
        int(value, 2)
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('{!r} is not a valid binary value'.format(value))
    return value

group.add_argument('-r', type=binary)

group.add_argument('-l', type=binary)

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.s and args.p is None:
    parser.error('You must use -p when -s is selected')
```

Comment: If `-s` had `nargs=2`, you would not need separate `-s` and `-p` arguments (and the test to make sure the user uses both).  Sensible defaults also let you skip the co-occurrence tests.